# PHP Pdo SELECT VIEW query fails

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to run the following query in PHP 7.1

```
$pdoClient->exec("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_view;

          CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
           select option_name,option_value from db1.options 
          UNION ALL 
           select option_name,option_value from db2.options;
");

$pdoClient->query("SELECT * from my_view WHERE option_name = 'blabla'";
```

I get the error

```
No database selected (SQLSTATE=3D000, CODE=1046).
```

But if I add database in Pdo constructor or add "USE db1;" statement above I get

```
Table 'db1.my_view' doesn't exist (SQLSTATE=42S02, CODE=1146).
```

For some reason it thinks that I am trying to run a table instead of a view.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are aware that you can pass the database to use in the PDO constructor?

Comment: You are missing `"`  in `$create `.Also pass database name while doing connection too

Comment: This is a psuedo code. Yes I pass the DB in constructor but doesn't help.

Comment: You cannot use more than 1 statement with a PDO query. Pass each statement in separately.

Comment: @aynber they're 2 statements.

Comment: Your create statement is 2 statements. Then you pass it in with `USE db1`, and you have 3 statements. Separate them out.

Comment: @aynber this doesn't matter. i cannot run any statement without USE db1; otherwise I get "No database selected" but i am doing a multi-database query.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you cannot pass more than 1 statement in via PDO. You need to separate them out like below. It's all treated as one connection, and it will run each command separately.

```
$create = "CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
           select option_name,option_value from db1.options 
          UNION ALL 
           select option_name,option_value from db2.options";
$pdoClient = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port", $user, $pass);
$pdoClient->exec("USE db1"); // Select the database
$pdoClient->exec("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_view");
$pdoClient->exec($create);
```

Once this is done, the select will work fine, like this:

```
$pdoClient->query($select);
```

Comment: I tried this. I still get Table 'db1.my_view' doesn't exist (SQLSTATE=42S02, CODE=1146).

Comment: and yes you can add multi statement in PDO.

Comment: Try checking for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) after the create statement to make sure it ran correctly.

Comment: Only if you have `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to off (which I often forget)

Comment: this is not the issue. the whole issue is that i cannot select from a view using PDO